# Can we use android:attr/spinnerStyle for TextView in Android

Tags: android, styles, android-styles

In my application i tried to change the Text color of my Spinner, By trying to change the Spinner's Text Color i have read like, **we can use** `TextView` **as Spinner by using the** `Style.xml` **as the following**...

In `Style.xml` as

```
<style name="spinners" parent="android:attr/spinnerStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
</style>
```

and in my XML file i used `TextView` as following

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinnerClassName"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        style="@style/spinners"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0" />
```

If i tried this Concept, i couldn't work with the `Spinner` operations with this `TextView`..

Help me, By giving yours Valuable Suggestions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom layout for your spinner where you can change your text color. Here is java example how to do this :

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
     R.layout.row, R.id.weekofday, new String[]{"ELEM 1","ELEM 2"}); // layoout.row is your custom layout. 
   mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Style spinner :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

and set that drawable as your background :

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner_chemical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
     android:background="@drawable/myspinner_background"/>
```

And for a ListView you can set style like this :

```
<style name="ListViewCustomStyle" parent="android:Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollTrackDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_holo</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_holo</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">0.5dip</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#e9e9e9</item>
    <item name="android:fadingEdge">none</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#00000000</item>
</style>
```

and that's the drawable used for styling the listview :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

<!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused_holo" />
</selector>
```

That's all.

Comment: can we change the Background color, while the List dropdown in the Spinner

Comment: Can we apply the Same for ListView.. I'm Using the ListView with MultipleChoiceMode??

Comment: I've just add info how to style a listview too.

Comment: How to set the Adapter for the ListView

Comment: `listview.setAdapter(adapter);` where adapter is your custom or another kind of adapter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll the text in `TextView` as if the text is much more than the size you allot to the `TextView` then you can add this below parameter in TextView at `layout-xml`

```
 android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Let me know, if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can depend on [appcompat-v7](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) and create your style element for example like this:

```
  <style name="FakeSpinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
  </style>
```